# How can i compare digits and add or remove some digits?

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem in comparing digits.

I have a text box. I want vb code that when  I put any number in text box, checks that it has 15 digits or not. If it has more, removes digits from end until it reach 15 digits.

If it has less, adds 0 to end until it reaches 15 digits. And writes the result in another textbox.

Comment: The textbox has a maximum length property to keep people from entering more than you want. You can always check the in the leave event to ensure that they have typed enough characters and if not, add your zeros.

Comment: No, its important to me that i recieve a number with 15 digits. Because i have a formula that this 15 digits number should goes there. So for ex if some one puts 627963 i want recieve 627963000000000

Comment: Never eluded to it not being important, just stated that you should set the MaxLength property to 15 this way you don't have to remove anything because they won't be able to add more than 15, and then check the actual length and `Pad` anything below 15 with 0's. Look up the `PadRight` method of the String Class.

Comment: Since your textbox value is probably a string, You can use the String.MID function to get the 15 digits you want, then use String.PadR to pad the result to a length of 15 with '0'.  Then convert to a numeric type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp
    Dim SelStart As Integer = TextBox1.SelectionStart
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.PadRight(15, "0"c).Substring(0, 15)
    TextBox1.Select(SelStart, 0)
End Sub
```

Edit-
To account for a negative number you will have to check for the existence of "-" and allow for 16 chars instead of 15. Also you will want to suppress keys that are not numeric, additionally you will only want to allow the "-" in the first position only.
That all might look something like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown

    Dim AllowedKeys() As Keys = {49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 48, 189, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 96, 109, 8, 46}
    If Not AllowedKeys.Contains(e.KeyData) Then e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    If TextBox1.SelectionStart > 0 AndAlso (e.KeyData = 109 Or e.KeyData = 189) Then e.SuppressKeyPress = True

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp

    Dim SelStart As Integer = TextBox1.SelectionStart
    TextBox1.Text = If(TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, 1) = "-",
        TextBox1.Text.PadRight(15, "0"c).Substring(0, 15),
        TextBox1.Text.PadRight(16, "0"c).Substring(0, 16))
    TextBox1.Select(SelStart, 0)

End Sub
```

Comment: If some one puts a mines number like -2678 digits will be 14. How to solve this?

Comment: @Armanoliya: If someone puts `3.1415926` in the textbox, how will that be handled? And if someone puts `ABC` in the textbox, how do you prevent your code from crashing? These issues probably require some explicit validation routine.

Comment: No worries, if this has solved your problem, please check the answer as answered. Thanks